# How can I remove spaces between Cards in ListView?

Tags: flutter, dart, listview, card

I'm working on flutter, and i wanna illustrate some Cards in the ListView, and i succeed.

then i wanna get rid of the horizontal spaces between Cards, I searched and found few solutions, but none of them worked.

How can I remove the spaces?

```
ListTile(
            title:Text("   Board list"),
            tileColor: Color(COLOR_PRIMARY2),
          ),
          for(Board myBoard in boardDataList)
            BoardSelector(myBoard.boardId), //a class draws card
          ],
```

Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there's an issue with your card class, try to remove any padding property by adding **EdgeInsets.zero**

Comment: I solved it ! very appreciate you .

Comment: Happy to help you!

Answer (score 2):

I think you set `margin: EdgeInsets.zero,` you refer **EdgeInsets** Class for official documentation [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/EdgeInsets-class.html) and `EdgeInsets.zero` [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/EdgeInsets/zero-constant.html) hope its help to you

```
      Card(
          margin: EdgeInsets.zero,
          child://Your Widget
        ),
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by modifying my code like below :

```
 return Card( 
      margin : EdgeInsets.all(1.0),
      child:
      ListTile(
```

Thank you.